# Not getting a response on already added list

Tags: javascript

I already wrote to enter the name of animal

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var node = document.createElement("li");
var textnode=document.createTextNode(name);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
```

I am trying to get to alert me if that name of animal already in the list entered.

```
if(document.createElement(name !== null)){
    alert();
```

This is the html section

```
    <ul id="demo">List Of Animals Already Present</ul>
```

Comment: 1) Mention "animal" as "entity".... 2) if(document.createElement(name !== null))     you have to first create the element and then check it for null    3) You need to identify which line goes in which order.. here's you are alerting if element couldn't get created..

Comment: Can i code demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can store the animals that was already created in an array, then loop through each to check if the name already exists, if not, then create a new node like the way you are doing.

this `if(document.createElement(name !== null))` statement that you are trying to use will not work, basically it was saying to create a new element but that element would be a `true` or `false`, because of the return of `name !== null`, so it will not create or check anything.

Here's a code that will probably help you:

```js
var animals = [];
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var alreadyExist = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){
    if (name == animals[i]){
      alreadyExist = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!alreadyExist){
      animals.push(name);
      var node = document.createElement("li");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(name);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
      document.getElementById('name').value = '';
   }else{
      alert('animal already in the list');
   }
}
```

```html
<input id="name" value="" placeholder="Animal name..."/>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='create'/>
<ul id="demo">List Of Animals Already Present</ul>
```

Comment: Where do i do that... sorry i am new using this community

Comment: in the left, just side of my answer, there is an arrow up , a number and an arrow down, just below this, there is a "V" to click

Comment: it changed to green

Comment: yeah, that's it.